# How to reference a index field from fk model in admin

Tags: django

I want to made a `thumbnail` in admin model. For now i have:

models.py

```
class ProductImages(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image_type = models.CharField(max_length=33,default='image_type')    
    image_file = models.ImageField(
        upload_to='images/',
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        default='magickhat-profile.jpg'
    )
```

admin.py

```
class AdminProductModel(admin.ModelAdmin):
        
    model = Product

    def product_thumb(self, obj):
        # return HTML link that will not be escaped
        return mark_safe(
            '<img src="%s" style="width:30px;height:30px;">' % (ProductImages.image_file.url)"""here is my doubt, i need only 1 image"""
        )

    list_display = ['product_thumb','user','slug','created_at']
    ...
```

Well, the `ProductImages` model store all images related with `Product` model, and i need get 1 image related to made `thumbinail` in admin

Comment: Try `obj.image_file.url` instead of `ProductImages.image_file.url`

Comment: tks for atention, but get error: `'Product' object has no attribute 'image_file'` @Ahtisham

Comment: Try this `ProductImages.objects.filter(product=obj).first().image_file.url`

Comment: @Ahtisham that is the way, tks work good...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in `mark_safe` function:

```
ProductImages.objects.filter(product=obj).first().image_file.url
```